# When I press . (period) Eclipse tries to compile

Tags: eclipse

As the title states, every time I press . on the keyboard, I get a popup message saying "This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project.". Now keep in mind I'm not even trying to compile at this point, i'm just trying to type a . without the program trying to compile my unfinished code on me. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`.` is usually treated as an auto-activation character when it comes to invoking content assist, and providing content assist often involves trying to compile what it can from the potentially broken syntax in your source file.

Reference for the relevant Preference page if you want to disable or otherwise alter this behavior: http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-content-assist.htm?cp=1_4_2_0_5_0

Really, though, you should tell it that the correct parent folder of your source file is a Source folder (what ever would make your package structure match the folder structure). The automatic background feedback that shortens your edit/compile/run loop is one of the main reasons to use an IDE instead of another text editor that happens to provide syntax coloring.